# Tf objection detection API deployment on django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

I am currently trying to serve into a webapp build in Django however I am facing some difficulties.
1. I have succesfully trained my model and I have the precious frozen_inference_graph.
2. I am creating the webapp on django.

I would like to call my model directly from my webapp folder. However, when using the inference method from my webapp folder, no inference is done: there is not bug and the script does nothing . In my tf folder, the script does the proper inference.

Do you have any clues? Also I have not found any tutorial for serving tensorflow on Django, are you aware of some?

Thanks,
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

You could serving your model.

> TensorFlow Serving is a flexible, high-performance serving system for machine learning models, designed for production environments. TensorFlow Serving makes it easy to deploy new algorithms and experiments, while keeping the same server architecture and APIs. TensorFlow Serving provides out-of-the-box integration with TensorFlow models, but can be easily extended to serve other types of models and data.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving

good luck!

Comment: Hi JiangKui, Thanks for your clue, that is what I am going to do :)